# LaTeX \bullet symbol in mtext

Tags: r, latex

I would like to print a symbol similar to LaTeX \bullet (a black circle) in a plot margin text. I have tried the unicode equivalent U2022 but it prints out as a small empty square. The symbol is not listed in the `plotmath` help page.

Here is an example:

```
plot(0,0)
mtext(side=2,at=0.25,text=bquote(y[paste(i,",",o)]),las=2)
```

I would like to replace the small "o" in the margin text by a small black disc of the same size.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be unicode 2022?

Comment: yes. I edited the post.

Comment: This works fine for me: `mtext(side=2,at=0.25,text=bquote(y[paste(i,",\U2022")]),las=2)`

Comment: yes, it does. I had probably made a typo. However, the U2022 symbol is much smaller than latex \bullet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Lyngbakr comment and after going through all unicode characters, U25CF looks more similar to \bullet.

```
mtext(side=2,at=0.25,text=bquote(y[paste(i,",\U25CF")]),las=2)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Presumably, I don't have the correct font installed or something...

Comment: Well, I just noticed it doesn't work with all font families. (hence, the empty square in my first test as I was using family="serif"). It work with "sans" on a mac.